# PyTorch Model is not training

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a problem that I can't fix already for a week. I am trying to build CIFAR-10 classifier, but my loss value after each batch is jumping randomly, and accuracy is not improving even on same batch (I can't even overfit model with one batch), so i guess the only possible reason is - weights are not updating.

**My Module class**

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv_pool = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))

    self.fcnn = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512, 2048),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(2048, 2048),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(2048, 10)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv_pool(x)
    x = x.view(-1, 512)
    x = self.fcnn(x)
    return x
```

Optimizers I am using:

```
net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

My Train function:

```
def train():
for epoch in range(5):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    for i in range(0, df_size):
        # get the data

        try:
            images, labels = loadBatch(ds, i)
        except BaseException:
            continue

        # wrap 
        inputs = Variable(images)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(inputs)

        loss = criterion(outputs, Variable(labels))

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        acc = test(images,labels)
        print("Loss: " + str(loss.data[0]) + " Accuracy %: " + str(acc) + " Iteration: " + str(i))

        if i % 40 == 39:
            torch.save(net.state_dict(), "model_save_cifar")

    print("Finished epoch " + str(epoch))
```

I am using **batch_size** = 20, **image_size** = 32 (CIFAR-10)

**loadBatch** functions returns tuple of **LongTensor** 20x3x32x32 for images and **LongTensor** 20x1 for labels

I would be really happy if you can help me, or suggest possible solution ( I have a guess that it's because sequential modules in NN, but parameters that I am passing to optimizer seems to be right)

Comment: At first glance, seems fine to me. Can you also post your test function?

Comment: @blckbird check my answer if you are interested. Test function was just iterating through test_set and comparing output labels with train_set labels

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I figured out what's the problem. I was trying to convert image to tensor by myself, and seems I messed up with dimensions of the image + I was watching SGD steps sequentially, and not in batches. Now I am checking every 25 batches and it's most of the time ok, depends on NN and data. Here's my code to load data, I hope someone will find it helpful

**Goods dataset** is Dataset for loading images from folder, and csv file that contains column **category** as label and **id** as image file id

I suggest to use pytorch image processing functions and **Pillow** Image.Open

```
batch_size = 8
img_size = 224

transformer = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])



class GoodsDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        self.le.fit(self.data.loc[:, 'category'])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.data.loc[idx, 'id']) + '.jpg')
        image = (Image.open(img_name))
        good = self.data.iloc[idx, :].as_matrix()
        label = self.le.transform([good[2]])
        return [transformer(image), label]
```

Then you could just use:

```
train_ds = GoodsDataset("topthree.csv", "resized")
train_set = dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)
```

And in your train function iterate through train_set with **enumerate**, this will give you index **i** and tuple of image and label, encoded with **Label Encoder** that is inside Dataset.

Good luck!